# Table data vs. text data in a blog post

Tags: php, database, datatable, wysiwyg

I usually work with tabular data that come from a specific table that I created myself as part of the site database. How about tables that aren't site tables, like tables that are just part of a blog post?

The thing about these tables is that they vary from post to post. Each post would have text and many paragraphs, but one post could have a table that compares PHP, Java, and Python. Then another post compares 2 masters programs, and so on. The tables vary, and some posts might not have any tables at all, and other posts might have multiple tables, so I don't know if creating database tables for them makes sense here.

So what's the most logical way to add these tables as part of a blog post? I would really prefer to have them easily editable as well. Any suggestions for a good way to do this?

Comment: I don't understand. What aspect of inserting the tables is your question about? Which element to use? Which editor to use?

Answer (score 1):

Use [WYSIWYG editor](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/WYSIWYG_editor). Both [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/) or [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) would fit your needs.

Try:

- [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/tryit/full.php)
- [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/demo)

You can find tables samples in both demos.

Answer (score 1):

You can save your tables in the database and add them to the post with marco like `{table: 1}`. And you can make table editor separately from post editor.

Comment: I think the macro is a good idea. Can you tell me more how to implement this? Would I use a regex or what?

Comment: @sameold Yes, I think regexp is the best solution for this problem.